# Running out of index in binary search

Tags: python-3.x

```
###Binary Search###
def search(list1,n):
    l=0
    u=len(list1)
    

    print(u)
    while l<=u:
        mid = (l+u)//2

        if list1[mid]==n:
            global index1 
            index = mid
            return True
            
        else:
            if list1[mid]<n:
                l = list1[mid]
            else:
                u = list1[mid]

list1 = [4,7,8,12,45,99.102,702,10987,56666]
n = 12
list1.sort()

if search(list1, n):
    print("Found at ",index)
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

The error I am getting is:

```
line 26, in <module> if search(list1, n): line 11, in search if list1[mid]==n: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: In your list 1, you have put a dot instead of comma between 99 and 102. Change it and then run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your the `u` in your code is supposed to be the high pointer. In that case it should be initialized to `len(list1) - 1` and in the end the left and right pointers should be set to `l = list1[mid+1]` and `u = list1[mid-1]`. For binary search its always easier to implement the recursive method. Find out more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-binary-search/)